# cannot find any saved .csv files

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I did search through many of the .csv realated topics that the search returned so I hope this is an appropriate new question...

I am trying to setup an excel spreadsheet using a .csv file as the data source, very simple but here's the issue; I cannot find ANY .csv file I have saved after exporting it from the program in which I run my report from. I export and save the report, type my desired file name and am able to chose from tab or comma delimited files. I have saved to my desktop, documents folder, favorites, etc. When I search for the files in my computer or the import data window in Excel, they are nowhere to be found even when typing the exact file name in the search bar. If I go back to my report and re-export it, I can see the file already saved and will even prompt me if I attempt to save using the same name.

I have gone into folder settings and verified all hidden items are showing, I'm at a complete loss and have spent quite a fair amount of time browsing for a solution today.

Win 7 enterprise btw...not sure if that matters.

Thanks as always!

Comment: When you save your file to the desktop, do you see the file on the desktop?

Comment: no, cannot see it on the desktop or anywhere else. Can't even find it using a search.

Comment: When you go back and re-export your CSV file, while still in the Save As window, right-click one of the existing CSV files and click Properties, then examine the General, Security, and Details tab for anything unusual.  One thing that comes to mind is that the files are being saved in an unexpected location (General tab) or with security permissions that prevent them from being seen through Windows Explorer (Security tab).  Consider posting some screen shots of these property windows.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the report tool is running under different user than your own.

From the report tool Open/Save dialog, right-mouse-click on the file you've just saved, select *Copy*, move in the dialog to **C:\Users\<*your user name*>\Desktop**, right-click and select *Paste*. The file should now be visible on your own Desktop. If you cannot access files in your own user name in ***C:\Users**, then you will either need to run the report tool under your credentials, or you'll need access to run under the tool's credentials.

Another possibility is that the report tool is saving it under another name, or with a different extension, from that shown. In that case, look for *any* new files in the expected directory, and open them with Notepad to see if they are indeed the CSV files.

Comment: I am unable to copy paste. I've exhausted all efforts to save to different folders and locate the file. I've also noticed that while I can see my previously saved .csv file if I attempt to re-export and save it, after a period of time it disappears all together as if it were deleted.

I am attempting to contact support in the event the application is to blame, I can locate, open, etc. .csv files that I create and save myself from notepad.

Answer (score 1):

This was the resolution to my issue, though I believe this may be unique to the application I use, and I was not able to figure out the reasoning behind it as the vendor was unable to assist, it was the fix nonetheless.

[image]

From the typical save as window shown above, I had to select the highlighted drop-down list, navigate to Local Disk (C:) > users > "me" > then the desired folder.

This would not work and would result in a "ghost file" if the C drive were selected via the panel on the left or one of the icons in the main window. This is the only resolution I've found for exporting files to any other location or shared drive as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which lead me here - it was solved by saving through C\Users\My Name\Desktop....created a new folder and saved it.  I then navigated to this same location through Excel and Windows Explorer and it's now there, though it's still not appearing directly on my desktop - but problem solved!  Thank you, I spent WAY too long trying to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score -2):

You have probably given up or found a solution.... but for anyone else out there..... try looking in your temp docs file. I just went through absolute hell trying to find a doc I had worked on for 10 hours. It wasn't showing up in my recent docs or any search I could run. I was panic stricken. I knew I had saved it. It was in the temp docs folder.. which apparently doesn't show up in recent docs or searchs...

C:\Users\your name\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: I actually forgot this was never resolved. My assumption is, it's due to the application I am exporting from but will leave an answer as to what the required steps were for locating these files, in my unique situation anyway, using the application Epic.